# Issu with TextFields and TableView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Hello (back to those which helped me before),

I ask a new question on my code. So before, i had an issu with adding my combobox value on my tableview, and i succesfully fix it. But now, i can't add my textfields "text" in my table (which was not a problem before), so can you help me an second time ? (im french so firstly, sorry for my english, and secondly, i tried to translate all my arguments and others in english for a better understand).

I link you a picture of the actual result:
[Result with text in the 2 TextFields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUYgC.png)

```
public class Tableviewex extends Application {

private TableView<Shop> table = new TableView<>();
private ObservableList<Shop> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<String> productlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Doliprane","Spasfon");
private Pane layout = new Pane();
private HBox hb = new HBox();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
    stage.setWidth(450);
    stage.setHeight(550);

    final Label label = new Label("Choose your medication ");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));



    TableColumn<Shop, String> productcol = 
        new TableColumn<>("Product");
    productcol.setMinWidth(200);
    productcol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<>("product"));



   productcol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Shop>forTableColumn());
    productcol.setOnEditCommit(
        (CellEditEvent<Shop, String> t) -> {
            ((Shop) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                ).setProduct(t.getNewValue());
    });


    TableColumn<Shop, String> quantityCol = 
        new TableColumn<>("Quantité");
    quantityCol.setMinWidth(100);
    quantityCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<>("Quantité"));
    quantityCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Shop>forTableColumn());
    quantityCol.setOnEditCommit(
        (CellEditEvent<Shop, String> t) -> {
            ((Shop) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setQuantity(t.getNewValue());
    });

    TableColumn<Shop, String> priceCol = new TableColumn<>("Prix");
    priceCol.setMinWidth(100);
    priceCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<>("Prix"));
    priceCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Shop>forTableColumn());       
    priceCol.setOnEditCommit(
        (CellEditEvent<Shop, String> t) -> {
            ((Shop) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setEmail(t.getNewValue());
    });

    table.setItems(data);
    table.getColumns().addAll(productcol, quantityCol, priceCol);

    final ComboBox<String> choixproduit = new ComboBox<>();
    choixproduit.setItems(productlist);
    choixproduit.setPromptText("Choose your medication");
    choixproduit.setMaxWidth(productcol.getPrefWidth());
    final TextField addQuantity = new TextField();
    addQuantity.setMaxWidth(quantityCol.getPrefWidth());
    addQuantity.setPromptText("Quantity");
    final TextField addPrice = new TextField();
    addPrice.setMaxWidth(priceCol.getPrefWidth());
    addPrice.setPromptText("Price");

    final Button addButton = new Button("ADD");
    addButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        data.add(new Shop(
                choixproduit.getValue(),
                addQuantity.getText(),
                addPrice.getText()));
        addQuantity.clear();
        addPrice.clear();
    });

    hb.getChildren().addAll(choixproduit, addQuantity, addPrice, addButton);
    hb.setSpacing(3);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb);


    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox,layout);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static class Shop {

    private final SimpleStringProperty product;
    private final SimpleStringProperty quantity;
    private final SimpleStringProperty price;

    private Shop(String fProduct, String quantity, String price) {
        this.product = new SimpleStringProperty(fProduct);
        this.quantity = new SimpleStringProperty(quantity);
        this.price = new SimpleStringProperty(price);
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product.get();
    }

    public void setProduct(String fProduct) {
        product.set(fProduct);
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity.get();
    }

    public void setQuantity(String fProduct) {
        quantity.set(fProduct);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return price.get();
    }

    public void setEmail(String fProduct) {
        price.set(fProduct);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your `CellValueFactory`s of your `quantityCol` and `priceCol` columns have not the good `String`. It should be `quantityCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));` and `priceCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));`. It should respect the name of your `Shop ` attributes.

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot for your help, i have a question about the code, why do we write "        this.quantity = new SimpleStringProperty(quantity);
        this.price = new SimpleStringProperty(price); " and dont use it in arguments in the void arguments ? (we actually use the "fProduct" argument)

Comment: What do you mean ? What will be the interest to get a constructor with arguments (fProduct, quantity and price) and not to store them in the attributes ?

Comment: Yes exactly ! can you explain me ?

Comment: Ahaha, we do not understand each other. I will try to explain what I've understood from your question : by writing this `this.quantity = new SimpleStringProperty(quantity)` in the constructor, you basically say that you know the quantity value as soon as you instantiate your `Shop` object. It avoids you to set the value with the setter (`setQuantity`) after having instantiating the `Shop` object.

Comment: Ah maybe I get what disturbs you. Change your constructor by this : `public Shop(String pProduct, String pQuantity, String pPrice) {}` . I've added the **p** prefix (for **p**arameter) and in your constructor set your attributes like this : `this.product = new SimpleStringProperty(pProduct);`, `this.quantity = new SimpleStringProperty(pQuantity);` and `this.price = new SimpleStringProperty(pPrice);`. I think you confused the attributes with the parameter because they have the same name but it is two different object.

Comment: I change them and i fully understand, i confused the attributes and parameters, thanks a lot for your help ! Sorry but i have a last question, if i want ( and i really want aha) to put a price to each medication in my observablelist, and put them in the third column without writing it ( so the price texfield will be delete and each medication will have a unique price), how i need to process ?

Comment: It begins to be interesting. I let you look for a solution (it is the best way to learn). And if you're stuck by an error or by an unexpected behaviour, come back again on stackoverflow and create a new post :). Good luck.

Comment: No problem, thank you a lot, btw i see you live in Nantes, do you speak french ?

Comment: Yes I do :) (but as this site could help everyone, I only speak english here :) ).